# OneNote API - Export a OneNote notebook page as another file format

Tags: onedrive, onenote, onenote-api

I have looked around quite a bit and cannot seem to find any material that confirms or denies the ability to do this. Using the Microsoft Graph or OneNote API, I would like to export a users Notebook and/or Section in one of the formats that the OneNote 2016 desktop application is capable of exporting as: .one, .pdf, .xps, .mht. Is this possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The OneNote API exports OneNote content as HTML, so in theory you should be able to write an app that translates that to any of the contents you described.

Answer (score 0):

A call to the API via

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages/xxx/content?includeinkML=true&preAuthenticated=true

will retrieve text in HTML format, links to images or files on a page, and ink in InkML format ([see Jorge's post on this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2017/07/07/onenote-ink-beta-apis/)).

Assemblying this into a pdf probably makes the most sense (using javascript or php libraries).